# Get Drive letter from Volume ID

Tags: powershell

I want to use drive letter instead of Volume ID like below. How can I do that ?

Thanks,

My output :

```
VolumeName                                                  OriginatingMachine  InstallDate
\\?\Volume{3c0a6eed-1b4c-4e90-a25b-8af1af46e368}\           app01.contoso.com   4/13/2021 6:03:34 PM
\\?\Volume{de5c18ac-56e1-4efa-afb4-abaf476a99a9}\           app01.contoso.com   4/13/2021 6:03:34 PM
```

My desired output :

```
VolumeName  OriginatingMachine  InstallDate
E:          app01.contoso.com   4/13/2021 6:03:34 PM
X:          app01.contoso.com   4/13/2021 6:03:34 PM
```

Command:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_ShadowCopy | Where InstallDate -lt ([datetime]::Now.AddDays(-5)) | Select-Object VolumeName,OriginatingMachine,InstallDate
```

Get-CimInstance Win32_ShadowCopy  output :

```
Caption            :
Description        :
InstallDate        : 9/17/2021 9:22:06 PM
Name               :
Status             :
ClientAccessible   : False
Count              : 11
DeviceObject       : \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1234
Differential       : True
ExposedLocally     : False
ExposedName        :
ExposedPath        :
ExposedRemotely    : False
HardwareAssisted   : False
ID                 : {3C8DAB36-F083-4C68-84BA-E339B8A18AF3}
Imported           : False
NoAutoRelease      : True
NotSurfaced        : False
NoWriters          : False
OriginatingMachine : app01.contoso.com
Persistent         : True
Plex               : False
ProviderID         : {B5946137-7B9F-4925-AF80-51ABD60B20D5}
ServiceMachine     : app01.contoso.com
SetID              : {D3D15CE2-9FFC-4A22-B03C-77D7FCB7D40E}
State              : 12
Transportable      : False
VolumeName         : \\?\Volume{85e62cfa-2e9c-4a46-af5a-f0748acd60b6}\
PSComputerName     :
```

Comment: Can you try accessing `DeviceObject`?. Ie, `Select-Object DeviceObject,OriginatingMachine,InstallDate`

Comment: I want to use drive letter instead of Volume ID like below. not device object. I hve upload sample Get-CimInstance Win32_ShadowCopy output :

Comment: If you just need this for the local machine, you can use `Get-Volume -UniqueID` with the value from the `VolumeName` property from the Win32_ShadowCopy output.

Answer (score 2):

The `Win32_ShadowCopy` command returns `Win32_ShadowCopy` objects, which have a number of fields [all described here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394428(v=vs.85)#examples)

Some of the fields provided in ShadowCopy happen to match other WMI Classes which have info about Drive Letters, namely the `VolumeName` field.  This field happens to also be present on both the `ShadowCopy` and `Win32_Volume` class, the latter of which has the drive letter property we need!

All we have to do is lookup all of the shadow copies, then lookup all of the volumes on the machine, then we can loop through the copies to find the matching volumes.  If you have some really complex mounting logic, you'll need to add some extra logic though in the `foreach` section.

So we would make a quick little function to do this lookup for us, which would look like this:

```
function Get-Win32ShadowVolumeDiskInfo{
    $shadowCopies = Get-CimInstance Win32_ShadowCopy
    $volumes = Get-CimInstance Win32_Volume
    $returnObject = @()

    foreach ($copy in $shadowCopies){
        $matchingVolume = $volumes | Where DeviceID -eq $copy.VolumeName
        $returnObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
            VolumeName=$matchingVolume.Name;
            OriginatingMachine = $copy.OriginatingMachine;
            InstallDate = $copy.InstallDate}
    }

    $returnObject
}
```

Comment: thanks btw, how can we add "Where InstallDate -lt ([datetime]::Now.AddDays(-5)) " ?

Comment: You'd run this:  `Get-Win32ShadowVolumeDiskInfo | Where InstallDate -lt ([datetime]::Now.AddDays(-5)) `

Comment: I would prefer `([datetime]::Now.AddDays(-5).Date)` to set that reference date to midnight. Also, please don't do `$returnObject += [PSCustomObject]@{..}`, instead just have the loop simply output the [PSCustomObject]. Other than that, + 1

Comment: Have to agree with @Theo here too. +1 as well!

Comment: Good suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is curious why they suggested that, arrays in PowerShell aren't really mutable and are torn down and recreated for every `+=` operation.  With very large numbers, this becomes a big deal and a huge performance slowdown.

Comment: Hi ,  I have a question related to the toast notifications. have you had a chance take a look this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113466/toastnotification-how-to-change-the-font-color-and-also-how-to-make-the-backgro